# Adding the load more button from my front page to my search page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my front page I have my posts set up as 1 post on a row, 2 rows of 2 posts on a row, 1 post on a row, and so on. Then after every 15 posts the load more button appears (example below). The load more button works perfectly, so I am trying to duplicate it on my search page.

I would like to add the same load more button to my search page.  However, I have my posts set up differently on this page, I just have 2 posts on each row (there is no alternating col-12 post).  In addition to the different loop structure I would like to add the load more button after every 8 posts (example below).  I have duplicated the loop structure for my front page in my functions.php, and adjusted it to fit the different loop structure and the load more button after every 8 posts.  However, it will not work correctly.  The first 8 posts are showing up how I want them, 4 rows of 2 posts per row.  But after you press the load more button, the posts show up as they do on my front page loop (15 posts of 1 post on a row, 2 rows of 2 posts on a row, 1 post on a row, and so on).

Does anyone know how I could fix this?  Or achieve a search page of 4 rows with 2 posts per row?  Thanks in advance.

how my front-page looks

[image]

how I want my search page to look

[image]

my front-page.php

```html
<?php

get_header();
get_template_part ('post-template/trendingg'); 
?>



<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
                paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
                posts_per_page: 15  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
            },
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 15, // i use 1 for testing
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;
        }?>
    <?php
}?>
</section>

<button id="load_more_btn">Load More Posts</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

my functions.php front page loop

```html
//FRONT PAGE
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');

function my_load_more_function() {

    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"])
    ] );


    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

            if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
 <div class="row">
                    <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
                        <div class="large-front-container">
                            <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
                        <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                        <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="front-page-post-info">
                            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                            <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            <?php } else { // Small posts ?>
                <?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?>
                                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></a>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;

        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

my search.php

```html
<?php

get_header();
?>
    <div class="search-results-search">
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form-search form-inline-search" action="">
            <div class="input-group-search">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm-search search-field-search form-control-search" placeholder="<?php echo $s ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'my_search_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
                paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
                posts_per_page: 15  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
            },
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 8, // i use 1 for testing
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

   if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
        }?>

</section>

<button id="load_more_btn">Load More Posts</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

my functions.php search loop

```html
//SEARCH PAGE
add_action('wp_ajax_my_search_load_more_function', 'my_search_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search_load_more_function', 'my_search_load_more_function');

function my_search_load_more_function() {

    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"])
    ] );


if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

   if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?>
                <?php
    

        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

My first initial 8 search results are the correct search results.  However, after I press the load more button it loads all my posts starting from the most recent.

** Updated search.php

```html
<?php

get_header();
?>
    <div class="search-results-search">
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form-search form-inline-search" action="">
            <div class="input-group-search">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm-search search-field-search form-control-search" placeholder="<?php echo $s ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



<script>
    var now=2; // when click start in page 2

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
    action: 'my_load_more_function_s', // the name of the function in functions.php
    paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
    posts_per_page: 8,  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
},
            success: function (data) {

            if(data!=0){
                jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
                now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
            }else{
                jQuery("#load_more_btn").hide();
            }
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="ajax"><!-- i have to change div to section, maybe a extra div declare -->
<?php

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 8, // i use 1 for testing
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
      's' => $s,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) //page number 1 on load
] );

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();

   if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
        }?>

</section>

<button id="load_more_btn">Load More Posts</button> <!-- button out of ajax container for load content and button displayed at the bottom -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

**Updated functions.php search loop

```html
//SEARCH PAGE
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function_s', 'my_load_more_function_s');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function_s', 'my_load_more_function_s');

function my_load_more_function_s() {
    global $query_string;

    $search_query = wp_parse_str( $query_string );
    $search = array_merge($search_query, [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"]),
        's' => $_POST['s']
    ]);

    $query = new WP_Query($search);


if ($query->have_posts()) {

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();

   if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '<div class="row">';} ?>
                <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>>
                    <div class="two-front-container">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                        <div>
                    <div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
                    <div class="front-page-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <div class="front-page-post-info">
                        <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/share-buttons' ); ?>
                        <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0){ echo '</div>';}?>
                <?php
            }
        }else{
        return 0;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Comment: i believe @sysix has provided the correct answer. Kindly update if not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must at first your ajax call and give the search value too.

from `search.php`

replace your start code with:

```js
var now=2; // when click start in page 2
var searchValue = <?php echo json_encode(['s' => $s]); ?>;

jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'my_load_more_function_s', // the name of the function in functions.php,
            s:  searchValue.s, // the value from the input
            paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
            posts_per_page: 8,  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
        },
```

encode your `s` variable with json_encode

And then change your ajax function like this:

```php
function my_load_more_function_s() {
    global $query_string;

    $search_query = wp_parse_str( $query_string );
    $search = array_merge($search_query, [
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
        'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged', $_POST["paged"]),
        's' => $_POST['s']
    ]);

    $query = new WP_Query($search);
```

The `s`-parameter can be found in the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter).

After reading more about the search page. I found, that you must use the `global $query_string`. You can find this in the [docs too](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination)

---

For don't forget it, you can save the number in php and output for javascript like:

```js
data: {
    action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
    paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
    posts_per_page: <?php echo $number; ?>  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
}
```

Comment: So when I change it to the suggested code it works at only showing 8 posts on every load.  However, it is calling the post loop from my_load_more_function.  So I tried to change it to my search function (in my original question) to my_search_load_more_function, but now when I press the load more button a pop up box pops up saying localhost:888 says: [object Object]

Comment: I have to use a different loop because as I mentioned in my original question the post layout on my front page is different from the post layout I am trying to achieve on my search page.  On my front page I have every 7th post col-md-12, however on my search page I want to get rid of the every 7th posts and have them all be col-md-6

Comment: can you look in your network analyse tool (inbuild in browser), what he response of your ajax call is. I think that this produce some of php error/warning.

Comment: I found a mistake in my functions.php search loop.  I was using $the_query when I should have been using $query.  Now it works so that every time I press the load more button it will load 8 more posts.  However, there is another issue.  My first initial 8 search results are the correct search results.  However, after I press the load more button it loads all my posts starting from the most recent.  How could I fix this so that after I press the button it will continue loading search results?  I have added updated code above.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working correctly.  The first initial 8 posts show the correct search results.  However each time I load a new set of 8 posts it is just pulling my most recent posts.

Comment: You can see my updated functions above - the same problem is still happening.  The first initial 8 posts show the correct search results. However each time I load a new set of 8 posts it is just pulling my most recent posts

Comment: updated answer again. the search page must be customized.

Comment: Updated what my search.php and functions.php looks like.  Now when I press the load more button nothing happens (even though there are more posts that should be loaded).

Comment: no php error?  what gives you give `var_dump($query)`. you can use pastebin.com for linking it

Comment: It should work, please check in the network tab of the developer console that "s" if defined in the post request. Maybe there is an issue with `s: $('.search-field-search').val()`, it may need to be replaced by `s: jQuery('.search-field-search').val()`.

Comment: I tried your updated answer.   The same problem is still happening, the first initial 8 posts are loaded perfectly, but when I press the load more button nothing happens.  So do you think it could be a problem with the functions.php, since it's only the loop that has the problem?

Comment: It doesnt work because the value of s is not set in the input field, you put it in placeholder attibute, not in the value one : `<input type="search" value="<?php echo $s ?>" name="s" class="input-sm-search search-field-search form-control-search" placeholder="<?php echo $s ?>">`

Comment: I added the js variable now via php. thanks for your info

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but the same problem is still happening.  Any other solutions?

Comment: can you remove unnecessary parts of your question? like front-page code and function loop code. And update your question so we can check if we are missing something